# Can't disable the title select2 in 2 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have 2 modal at same page using select2. I need to remove title on hover select2 in modal select form. I have tried

```
  $('.select2-selection__rendered').hover(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('title');
    });
```

to remove the hover, but it only works in 1 modal. In the other modal at the same page, it still show hover title.

Here's the script modal 1

```
               <div class="form-group" id="form-class-1" style="margin-top: -10px">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="class">Class *</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <select id="class" class="form-control" name="class" style="width: 100%">
                                            <option value="" selected disabled>-- Choose Class --</option>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach ($class $c)
                                                {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$c->id.'">'.$c->class_name.' </option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's the script modal 2

```
      <div class="form-group" id="form-class-2" style="margin-top: -10px">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <label for="class">Class*</label>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <select id="clas" class="form-control" name="clas" style="width: 100%">
                                            <option value="" selected disabled>-- Choose Class --</option>
                                            <?php
                                                foreach ($class $c)
                                                {
                                                    echo '<option value="'.$c->id.'">'.$c->class_name.' </option>';
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With your JS condition it only select the modal where it's hover because of $(this)

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').hover(function () {
     $(this).removeAttr('title');
});
```

you should change it to `$( class of modal1 and modal2 ).removeAttr('title');`

also why the two modal have the same id in the same page `id="form-kelas1"`?

id should be unique per page.

Comment: does your 2 modal have the same class name where you want to remove the title?

Comment: yes, it is. Should I change modal class name first ?

Comment: no, can i see the html of the select2? where you are hovering it. and the html you want to hide the title?

Comment: like this ? `<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-class-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="-- Choose Class --">-- Choose Class --</span>` ? I want to empty the `title`, because I have tried in `inspect element` and it works

Comment: so this html <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-class-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="-- Choose Class --">-- Choose Class --</span>
you are hovering you want the title attribute to be empty? right. so does this <span> is inside the 2 modal or not?

Comment: yes, its inside the modal. In modal 1, span id is `select2-class-container`, in modal 2, span id is `select2-clas-container`.

Comment: do this. $('.select2-selection__rendered').hover(function () {
        $('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
}); @IkramShabri

Comment: it should work because you're selecting all '.select2-selection__rendered' and emptying it. check if you have different spelling in other span.

Comment: the span spell is correct, when I check `inspect element`, the title just empty in first modal, not in the second modal